# Match characters in a word using regular expression

Tags: regex

I have string like

```
"Rupeshposts-this-question"
```

I need a regular expression which can check whether the first word contains `Rupesh` and `posts` separately.

Something like `[Rupesh][posts]` this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really know what you are after but this is one way to separate one word into two parts:

```
find: (Rupesh)\B(posts)
replace: \1 -something in between - \2
```

Seems to be working also without `\B`: `(Rupesh)(posts)`.

This finds "Rupeshposts" but not "Rupesh posts"):

```
find: ((Rupesh)(posts))
replace: \2 -something in between - \3
```